# How to extract value using xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How to extract number 500 using xslt 1.0 from a large text

"o:errorCode" : "500"

Comment: You want to apply XSLT to text that is not XML?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and explain the rules that need to be applied, in addition to the example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($largeText, '&quot;o:errorCode&quot; : &quot;'), '&quot;')"/>
```

This extracts the substring between the first occurrence of `"o:errorCode" : "` in `$largeText` and the first `"` that follows it.

Note that this will fail if the formatting of the input changes.